# Get Image or its Headers Without Caching Cross-Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-cache

I'm trying to retrieve an image's size without caching it (for valid reasons) or get its `Content-Length` header without downloading the image itself. I need this information to match the remote image with a control one (if there is another way to achieve that with these constraints, I'm all ears).
The server is out of my control. Here is what I've tried so for:

1. With this script I can easily get the image, but can't prevent its caching:

   ```
   var img = new Image();
   img.src  = 'http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/themes/NASAPortal/images/nasa-logo.gif';
   ```
2. With this I get the headers in the debugger but I can't access them:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/themes/NASAPortal/images/nasa-logo.gif',
       type: 'HEAD',
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
   ```
3. <del>With this I get the image without caching, but I can't access its properties:</del>

   ```
   <iframe src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/themes/NASAPortal/images/nasa-logo.gif"></iframe>
   ```
4. I've tried every JSONP combination, including `converters` and `dataFilter` with no success.
5. I've explored the possibility to download just the first n bytes of the image (so that caching wouldn't be a problem), but it only seems possible with AJAX, which blocks the attempt because it's cross-domain and JSONP doesn't seem to work either.

In summary, I've tried everything I could read and think about... I spent the last 48 hours (and hundreds of fiddles) looking for a solution. I have the constant feeling that with the above pieces, there should be a way...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding a querystring to avoid caching

```
var img  = new Image();
var rand = (new Date()).getTime();;

img.src  = 'http://www.nasa.gov/ ... /images/nasa-logo.gif?r=' + rand ;
```

Comment: The images still gets cached (at least in FF 29). This forces the browser to re-download it every time, I believe.

Comment: Uh, if the browser re-downloads the image every time, it's not cached, which was the point ?

Comment: Well, the image is still visible in the browser's cache, which is what I can't have.

Comment: @chris - but using a random querystring makes it a "different" image, so it's not really cached. If you mean the fact that you can still see the image as a loaded resource in the console, there's no way around that, that's what happens when you load an image, regardless of cache.

Comment: I'm not worried about the console, but since the image I download contains confidential data, I can't leave it on the user's PC (browser's cache). Hence the need to prevent caching. Alternatively, is there a way to download only a little part of the image instead of the whole file? To do my checking, anything pseudo-unique would work, like file size, the first 100 bytes, or even last modified date.

Comment: If the image contains confidental data, you have a problem, as any image opened in the browser, even partially, would be available to the user, and all one has to do is check the source and get the URL, then visit the URL of the image, and you have the data. Seems like a really bad way to send sensitive data.

Comment: It is bad design indeed... but the link dies very quickly, so the danger is time-limited on that front. I guess I'm stuck here... do I really have to give up?

Answer (score 0):

You can serve your images with the following response header:

Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store

That will prevent the browser from caching it, including proxy servers.

Comment: As stated, no control on the servers unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the system millisecond and add '?time='+milliseconds at the end of the url, most http cache are based on the url as key, so you may get a new image on every request